# Distributed Tensorflow: how to achieve between-graph synchronous training without using tf.train.SyncReplicasOptimizer

Tags: opencv, tensorflow

I read the [distributed tensorflow example & instruction](https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/blob/master/tensorflow/g3doc/how_tos/distributed/index.md). As this instruction recommends, `tf.train.SyncReplicasOptimizer` can help achieve synchronous distributed training. However, `tf.train.SyncReplicasOptimizer` needs an optimizer as its first argument. Tensorflow has provided some optimizers, such as `tf.train.GradientDescentOptimizer`, `tf.train.AdamOptimizer` and so on.

I want to achieve k-means algorithm (which **does not** use any optimizer) with between-graph and synchronous fashion in distributed tensorflow environment. In this situation, is there a way to achieve between-graph&synchronous training? (Can we achieve **between-graph synchronous** training without using `tf.train.SyncReplicasOptimizer`?)

Comment: So you are trying to distribute K-means over multiple devices/workers? Can you use `with tf.device(...)` constructs to split your work?

Comment: Thanks! @Yaroslav Bulatov  I know `tf.device( )` can help replicate the same operation(s) on a set of devices (data parallelism). However, I need something to **synchronize** the result from every devices at each iteration, which just like what `tf.train.SyncReplicasOptimizer` does. Taking k-means as an example, because every device takes a batch of data as input and do the same computation , I need to aggregate/synchronize the results from all devices at every iteration to compute the new centroids.   Do you know how to synchronize without `tf.train.SyncReplicasOptimizer`

Comment: Things are synchronized by default. In other words, if you have variable `a` that depends on `b` and `c` on different devices, TensorFlow system will wait until both values are available to produce `a`

Comment: Thanks @YaroslavBulatov Your suggested method is to write a python script containing N `tf.device()` statements (N is the number of worker process) and run the script only in **one** node. That is to say I have to abandon the [instruction template](https://www.tensorflow.org/versions/r0.10/how_tos/distributed/index.html#putting-it-all-together-example-trainer-program) which defines a cluster for replicated training and this template script need to be run on **all** nodes.   Is that what you meant?

Comment: The example in your link is somewhat specific to gradient descent using gradient averaging on parameter server. Its somewhat complex because it was made to support a case when full computation graph can't fit in RAM of one machine. It's not clear to me how you would use this optimization approach for k means. If you can fit your computation graph in ram, you can just use tf.device statements to distribute the work among nodes. This is how things were meant to get distributed originally until distributed image net graph started pushing 70gb

Comment: Thank you!@YaroslavBulatov I won't use optimizer. A possible solution is:split the whole input data on N workers and at each iteration let each work i compute the new centroids_i(Variable on worker i) based on its spitted batch data and aggregate centroids_1 ...centroids_N to get the new centroids (Variable on a ps) for next iteration. I can use N tf.device statements to place N replicated operations (compute centroids_i based on its local spitted batch) on N workers and then run this script on one node. Is that what you mean by using tf.device? So I don't need to use tf.train.Server?